# Evaluating a math expression in a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
echo “Enter the value of variable x” 
read x 
echo “Enter the value of variable y” 
read y
answer="\( $x + $y \) \* \( $x + $y \) \* \( $x + $y \)  = $(( $x + $y ) * ($x + $y) * ($x + $y))"
```

I want a program to find (x+y)^3 and please let me know what should be the actual code

Comment: What sort of numbers are we looking at?integers or floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done simply using `bc` as:

```
$(echo "$(($x+$y))^3" | bc)
```

or simply using bash (thanks to lecodesportif):

```
$((($x+$y)**3))
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `bc`, you can use Bash builtin arithmetics instead:

`echo $((($x+$y)**3))`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a few parens.

Fixed:

```
answer="\( $x + $y \) \* \( $x + $y \) \* \( $x + $y \)  = $(( ($x + $y ) * ($x + $y) * ($x + $y) ))"
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

> let ANSWER=(x+y)**3